# My Android photo app will not display images from the camera because the images are too large

Tags: android, image, compression, android-camera, bitmapimage

Ok, I want my app to enable users to take a photo and for the photo to be viewable to them later on, within the app.

The problem is that the photos taken by the camera are to large to be displayed in the app.

This is the kind of error written to logcat when the attempt is made to display the new photo in the app:

```
Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (5312x2988, max=4096x4096)
```

So obviously I need to scale/resize the image before it is stored to the **mynewapp** folder on the device.

See the code below, where we try to load the **mynewfile.jpg** after it has been stored on the device, if we edit the file source to reference an image file that is 500x500, then that image **WILL** be displayed. But it **WILL NOT** display the **mynewfile.jpg** as it is too large.

Can someone tell me how to resize the image before it is save on the device?

Many thanks

Here is my code:

Obviously I have added the appropriate permission to the **AndroidManifest.xml** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
```

The following code is in **TakePhotoDocActivity.java**:

```
    package com.example.frankjones.glovebox;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.File;

    public class TakePhotoDocActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        // Set Camera Request
        static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;

        // Prepare variables
        protected Button mTakePhotoBtn;
        protected ImageView mTakePhotoImg;

        // Start onCreate method
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo_doc);

            // Set variables
            mTakePhotoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhotoBtn);
            mTakePhotoImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.takePhotoImg);

            // Listen to button
            mTakePhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File file = getFile();
                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAM_REQUEST);
                }
            }); // End listen to button

        } // End onCreate method

        private File getFile() {
            // Specify the directory we will store the file in
            File folder = new File("/storage/emulated/0/mynewapp/");

            // If the directory doesn't exist, create it
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            // Specify the filename with its directory
            File imageFile = new File(folder, "mynewfile.jpg");

            // Return the filename
            return imageFile;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // Display new photo in the ImageView
            mTakePhotoImg.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("/storage/emulated/0/mynewapp/mynewfile.jpg"));

            // Toast a success message
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_take_photo_doc, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

And lastly, this is the layout file **activity_take_photo_doc.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        tools:context="com.example.frankjones.glovebox.TakePhotoDocActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/takePhotoBtn"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Take photo" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/takePhotoImg"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_glovebox_launcher_v2" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: check this how to load bitmap efficiently you will get an idea http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me how to resize the image before it is save on the device?

You can't. You are not saving the image at all. The third-party camera app that you invoked is saving the image. You did not write the third-party camera app.

Your primary choices are:

1. Load the image in using `BitmapFactory`, `BitmapFactory.Options`, and `inSampleSize`, so it takes up less memory.
2. Use [a third-party image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) that will handle option #1 for you.
3. Use a third-party `ImageView` replacement that will handle option #1 for you, as part of other functionality (e.g., pinch to zoom), such as [this library](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view)

Also:

- Please do not hardcode paths. `/storage/emulated/0/` is wrong for hundreds of millions of people. Always use framework-supplied methods (mostly on `Environment` and `Context`) for getting at root directories of interest.
- Please do not clutter up the user's external storage with your own directory. Use `getExternalFilesDir()` (a method on `Context`, and so it is available on `Activity`) to get at a framework-supplied directory on external storage that is unique for your app.

Comment: Thank you for your input on this. Can you send me some sample code based on the code I've posted? I've been playing with BitmapFactory for days and getting no where...

Comment: @Camdenmoo: "Can you send me some sample code based on the code I've posted?" -- Stack Overflow is not a consulting service. "I've been playing with BitmapFactory for days and getting no where" -- this sample app demonstrates the use of `BitmapFactory` and `inSampleSize` for loading a pair of images out of assets, showing the effects of downsampling in terms of memory usage and resulting image qualtiy: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Bitmaps/InSampleSize

Answer (score 0):

Android does not well work with big images. I recommend using [RapidDecoder](https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder) to download (open) and scale. And [SubsamplingScaleImageView](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) for display it.